# How to setup i18next with Next.js 13^ for server and client components

Tags: reactjs, setup-project, i18next, next.js13

Next community, I am having trouble configuring my internationalization with the brand new [Next.js13](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13) I am also using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/).

I kindly ask for your assistance and may be few examples of a working setup.

This is what I have tried so far
(I am using the new "app" directory)

```
//next-i18next-config.js

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

```
// next.config.js

const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next-config')

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental: { appDir: true },
  i18n
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

```
public
├── favicon.ico
└── locales
    ├── de
    │   └── translation.json
    └── en
       └── translation.json
```

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
    "i18next": "^22.0.4",
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "next-i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
  },
```

**Server side problem** - Error on useTranslation

```
app/
├── approach
│   └── page.tsx
├── layout.tsx
├── loading.tsx
└── page.tsx
```

```
import { use } from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next' // I also tried 'react-i18next'

async function getApproachPage() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/page/approach`, {
    cache: 'no-store', // SSR getServerSideProps
  })

  return res.json()
}

const ApproachPage = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation() // Getting an Error here : (

  const data = use(getApproachPage()) // TODO: implement res data in page after setting up translations

  return (
    <h1>{t('approach.title')}</h1>
  )
}

export default ApproachPage
```

**Client side problem** - can't locate translation.json files

This is how I am doing the config in v12 and lower versions ([link](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#serversidetranslations))

One of the things I can't understand is how to do this in v13

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common', 'home'])),
    }, 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've finally figured out how to make a setup that actually works.

I was able to comprehend how to accomplish it thanks to this incredibly thorough guide. I'll pass it along here to anyone else who needs it

https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

Comment: I also followed this guide, but I encountered an error when I call "createInstance", 
it says that "createContext" does not exist. My error occured only in server side components. @Aleksandar can you please tell how you resolved it.

Comment: Yes sure, here is my setup for createInstance in index.ts do this:

`const initI18next = async (lng: string, ns: string) => {
  const i18nInstance = createInstance()
  await i18nInstance
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(resourcesToBackend((language: string, namespace: string) => import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)))
    .init(getOptions(lng, ns))
  return i18nInstance
} `

Comment: you may also want to see this settings.ts: `export const fallbackLng = 'en'
export const languages = [fallbackLng, 'de']
export const defaultNS = 'home'

export function getOptions (lng = fallbackLng, ns = defaultNS) {
  return {
    supportedLngs: languages,
    fallbackLng,
    lng,
    fallbackNS: defaultNS,
    defaultNS,
    ns
  }
}`

Comment: @MohamedBENKHOUYA same for me. Followed the guide but got the error. Did you figure anything for a fix?

Comment: Hello @RMalke, for me it was just a mistake in my part, I just imported a dependency incorrectly. I slowly reviewed the imports and I came across the error. I advise you to review your imports.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding 'use client' to the top of the file, you can't use client side state in server components

Comment: Thanks Remy, I probably should have mentioned it in my question but I have 'use client' my client side component, because this is the way to have a client side components in v13 and above, unfortunately it is not solving the problem.